# rxjs6 error handling when using switchMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

**EDIT: described bug is gone in version 6.2.1**

I migrated a Project from rxjs5 to rxjs6 with the (well working(!)) migration tool in the rxjs-tslint package. In some cases my error handling, which works fine before, didn't catch the error anymore.

Is there anything new about scoping and/or error propagation when using switchMap? And how can I catch the error again?

Here is a working example

```
Rx.of(undefined).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log("WORKING")),
  mergeMap(boom => boom),
  catchError(err => Rx.throwError("ERROR CATCHED"))
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
},(err) => {
  console.log("ERROR:", err);
})
```

Output:

```
WORKING
ERROR: ERROR CATCHED
```

Not working example:

```
Rx.of("foo").pipe(
  switchMap(() => Rx.of(undefined).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log("NOT WORKING")),
    mergeMap(boom => boom),
    catchError(err => Rx.throwError("ERROR NOT CATCHED"))
  ))
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
},(err) => {
  console.log("ERROR:", err);
})
```

Output:

```
NOT WORKING
ERROR: TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected.
       You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Comment: If you create `Rx.of(undefined)` Observable then `mergeMap(boom => boom)` doesn't make sense

Comment: correct! That's the Point. In some cases in my real code the streamed data (which is normally an array at the mergeMap point) is undefined, therefore there is the `catchError` that not get triggered in the second example.

Comment: Hmm. I deleted my previous comment, asking for an issue to be created, but I don't think I should have. This does look like a bug or behaviour that warrants discussion. Please [create an issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/new/choose) in the RxJS repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works, error message is printed inside error function scope. `mergemap` is supposed to return an observable but for this example it is purposely left out to return undefined value to trigger error.

```
const { of, throwError } = require('rxjs')
const { switchMap, tap, mergeMap, catchError } = require('rxjs/operators')

of('foo').pipe(
   switchMap(val => of(undefined).pipe(
   tap(() => console.log('NOT WORKING')),
   mergeMap(val => val),
   catchError(err => throwError("ERROR NOT CATCHED"))
  ))
).subscribe(
   data => console.log('success', data),
   error => console.log(error)
)
```

Comment: Oh cool. Looks like it was fixed  >= 6.2.1. With 6.2.0 it crashes with a not catched typescript error.

Comment: @fastr.de I have 6.4.0 and still the same use. I am using catchError alongside mergeMap inside a switchMap. Is it working for you?

Comment: @yuva I've the same issue with 6.4.0 did you find the problem